# Check all checkboxes in a list

Tags: jquery, html

I have an unordered list of checkboxes within LIs and SPANs.  When a button is pressed above the UL, how do I check all of the boxes in the list below?  I've tried a couple of variations like this, without success:

```
$(this).closest('ul').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', this.checked);
```

Comment: Is the button part of the `ul`?

Comment: And if it is a button, it wouldn't have a `checked` property, would it?

Comment: Can you include the relevant html?

Comment: Updated my answer, please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated my answer**

[nextAll();](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) is what you're looking for.

Use [Attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) or [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) like this:

```
var $elements = $('input#afterthis').closest('li').nextAll().find('input[type="checkbox"]');

$elements.attr('checked', 'checked');

$('body').append('There are ' + $elements.length + ' elements checked');
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/qwRSW/3/

Comment: This was what I needed.  Though, how do I count how many within that set are checked?

Comment: @BryanPotts You can count using length. (updating the answer, please wait)

Comment: @BryanPotts Updated my answer giving a new JSFiddle link, please check

Answer (score 1):

If the button is a sibling of the `<ul>`:

```
$('.myButton').click(function(){
    $(this).next('ul').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

So the HTML looks like:

```
<input type="button" class="myButton" value="Check all" />
<ul>
....
</ul>
```

This method allows you to have lots of `<ul>`'s, each controlled by their own button. Just repeat the HTML, no need to change the jQuery.